# How to use user variables with file provisioner in Packer?

Tags: packer

I have a packer json like:

```
"builders": [{...}],
"provisioners": [
          {
                "type": "file",
                "source": "packer/myfile.json",
                "destination": "/tmp/myfile.json"
           }
  ],
"variables": {
        "myvariablename": "value"
 }
```

and myfile.json is:

```
{
   "var" : "{{ user `myvariablename`}}"
}
```

The variable into the file does get replaced, is a sed replacement with shell provisioner after the file the only option available here?

Using packer version 0.12.0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this that worked?

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te no, sorry

Comment: You can have ansible drive packer, makes things more flexible as it is awesome at templating.

Comment: ansible is a procedural workflow which is not good for provisioning pipelines in the long term

Answer (score 12):

You have to pass these as environment variables. For example:

```
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell"
      "environment_vars": [
        "http_proxy={{user `proxy`}}",
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "some_script.sh"
      ],
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "proxy": null
  }
```

And in the script you can use `$http_proxy`

Comment: environment_vars works just for the shell provisioner, not for the file:
https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html

Answer (score 1):

So far I've come just with the solution to use file & shell provisioner. Upload file and then replace variables in file via shell provisioner which can be fed from template variables provided by e.g. HashiCorp Vault

Answer (score 0):

Yo may use OS export function to set environment and pass it to Packer

Here is a config using OS ENV_NAME value to choose local folder to copy from
`export ENV_NAME=dev` will set local folder to `dev`

```
{
  "variables": {
    ...
    "env_folder": "{{env `ENV_NAME`}}",
  },
  "builders": [{...}]
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "files/{{user `env_folder`}}/",
      "destination": "/tmp/"
    },
    {...}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -3):

User variables must first be defined in a variables section within your template. Even if you want a user variable to default to an empty string, it must be defined. This explicitness helps reduce the time it takes for newcomers to understand what can be modified using variables in your template.

The variables section is a key/value mapping of the user variable name to a default value. A default value can be the empty string. An example is shown below:

```
 {
 "variables": {
"aws_access_key": "",
 "aws_secret_key": ""
 },

"builders": [{
"type": "amazon-ebs",
"access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
"secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
// ...
}]
}
```

[check this link for more information](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/user-variables.html)

Comment: Thanks Favour, but the question is more about how to  use the variables in an external file (with file provisioner) used by Packer